# Studentized residuals and goodness-of-fit with robust linear regression

Tags: r, regression, robust

Could you please advise whether studentized residuals are meaningful when computed on a robust linear regression model using an M-estimator?

I'd like to use it to detect outliers by doing something like this:

```
rfit = rlm(y~x, data=d)
pt(rstudent(rfit), df=nrow(d)-3)
```

Is this reasonable? I'd be quite happy with a rather crude measure and I'd rather err on the conservative side.

I'm also wondering whether I should run some kind of diagnostic of the general goodness of fit on this robust model before doing this.

Comment: Have a look at the `fit.models` function in the [fit.models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fit.models/fit.models.pdf) package.  This provides a comparison of regression diagnostics of model fits using `lm` and `rlm`.